# What Do Sam and Bucky know?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-falcon-and-the-winter-soldier

During the events of episode six of The Falcon and the Winter Soldier, Bucky, Sam and Sharon remain in contact via those earpieces that the Marvel Universe seems to have in oversupply. They speak to each other simply by speaking, even in the midst of combat, in disparate locations.

During the course of all this

> Karli calls Sharon the Power Broker, which Sharon seems to confirm and points out that Sharon hired Batroc.

Wouldn't Sam and Bucky have heard this? They don't seem to take it into consideration at all later in the episode.

Comment: Why are you discounting the possibility that she turned it off or took it out? Also didn't they ring her in that episode (or the one before). I don't think the ear pieces work over distances that large.

Comment: I haven't seen anyone turn any comms off. They just talk and get responses unless something is taken out. I would have to rewatch to see if she uses it after that moment. In terms of distance, they were all already talking and hadn't shifted locations by that much.

Comment: @Paulie_D earlier in the series it is stated that Karli was tasked with getting the serum for the power broker and betrayed the PB. Sharon says much the same thing, with herself in that position (I gave you a job...)

Answer (score 5):

### No, because she's not wearing the comms during her conversation with Karli

We can clearly see the comms device in Sharon's ear earlier...

[image]

but it's not there during her conversation...

[image]

Comment: I don't have access or tech skill to do this, but are there any stills of her during the confrontations before the conversation with Karli, when she is talking to Sam and Bucky that show the ear piece?

Comment: Nope, there aren't...but the above answers your question.

Comment: It answers if it is in contrast to her wearing an obvious piece during the rest of the episode. i don't recall seeing one in Bucky's ear but he was talking to her. The Avengers earpieces seem to be worn well inside the ear, not always visible.

Comment: I pushed some shadow recovery into the images to make them a bit easier to see. Hope you don't mind.